# Find and replace multiple words JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to replace 1 word with another with JavaScript, the code i have is working as below:

```
$('#test').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('microsoft', 'Hi I am
replace'),('bob', 'bobart')    
});
```

The code works for the first instance and will replace Microsoft but will not change Bob, how can I add multiple words to be replaced into this?

Thank you

Comment: You have a syntax error: `,('bob'...` should be `.replace('bob'...`

Answer (score 2):

Use chaining of replace using `.replace('x','y').replace('a','b')`:

```
his.textContent.replace('microsoft', 'Hi I am replace').replace('bob', 'bobart')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var replacers = {"to_be_replaced_1": "by_this_1","to_be_replaced_2":"by_this_2"},
    stringToBeReplaced = "some text to_be_replaced_1";

$.each(replacers ,function(replaceable, replacer){
   stringToBeReplaced.replace(replaceable, replacer);
});
```